# Cant' download file embedded even after switching to iframe using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, iframe, download, browser-automation

I have automated selection of data using selenium but site displays report inside iframe, I want to download xlsx files which is part of iframe.
Cant download files iteratively and there is no url generated for downloading of file.

````
 cycle = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID,"CycleId"))
            for i in range(1,3):
                cycle.select_by_index(i)
                
                browser.execute_script("BindReportData();") 
                
                WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='report']/iframe")))
                WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ReportViewer1_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button")))
                browser.switch_to.default_content()
                time.sleep(60)
                
                iframe_var = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')
                browser.switch_to.frame(iframe_var)
                
                but = browser.find_element(By.ID,'ReportViewer1_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu')
                options = but.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a')
                browser.execute_script(options[1].get_attribute('onclick'))
                browser.switch_to.default_content()
```
```
```

Site is (https://soilhealth.dac.gov.in/PublicReports/GridFormNSVW) I want to iterate through all states,district,block,village and cycle to download file



I have already tried switching to iframe to locate element to download, used webdriver wait to avoid stale element exception.
It sometimes shows stale element exception   or timeout error
````